# By considering z[sqrt[-2]] show that x^2+2=y^3 only has two integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, factoring

By considering z[sqrt[-2]] show that x^2+2=y^3 only has two integer solutions, (+/-5,3)

I can see that N(x+i Sqrt[2])=y^3, I think x+i Sqrt[2] is prime in z[i Sqrt[2]] so y^(3/2) must be x+i Sqrt[2] but I don't really see how any of this helps. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you could be right, thank you for finding this for me, I looked for ages.

Comment: Also, putting here the obligatory link to the mathjax primer for how to type in $\LaTeX$ on this site for making posts much easier to read.  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference